# Convert the text string K & M to 10^3 & 10^6

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have data frame with column values -

```
[Themangoescosts$1K]
[needtopay20K,10Kdollarsmakesagrand]
```

I need to convert K - 10^3

I am not sure how to use the regex option to replace the match value at its location for the list in data frame column

Used the below regex to identify the K & M cases -

```
match = re.search("[\d.]+[KM]+", row)
```

And planned to use below to replace the items -

```
mp = {'K':' * 10**3', 'M':' * 10**6'}
df2['c'] = pd.eval(df2.offer2.replace(mp.keys(), mp.values(), regex=True).str.replace(r'[\d.]+[KM]+',''))
```

Which results in error -

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

Expected Output -

```
[Themangoescosts$1000]
[needtopay20000,10000dollarsmakesagrand]
```

Comment: Instead of `re.search` use `re.findall` then you can just use normal string replacing by using the indexes it gives.

Comment: Try `df['c'] = df['offer2'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})([KM])', lambda x: '{}000'.format(x.group(1)) if x.group(2) == 'K' else '{}000000'.format(x.group(1)) )`

Comment: I hadn't realized you could pass a callable to `pandas.Series.str.replace`.  Also, shouldn't this work? `m = {'K': '000', 'M': '000000'}; df2['offer2'].str.replace(r'(?<=\d)[KM]', lambda x: m.get(x.group()))` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, it works. I just am not sure of the little context in `(?<=\d)[KM]`. `r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})([KM])` is a bit more precise since it checks for 1 to 3 digits before `K` or `M`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew piRSquared thank you, both the solution worked, it was a good learning for me. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using

```
df['c'] = df['offer2'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})([KM])', lambda x: '{}000'.format(x.group(1)) if x.group(2) == 'K' else '{}000000'.format(x.group(1)) )
```

The point is that you may use a callable as the replacement argument when using `Series.str.replace`.

**Regex description**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\d{1,3})` - Group 1: one to three digits
- `([KM])` - Group 2: `L` or `M`.

The `lambda x: '{}000'.format(x.group(1)) if x.group(2) == 'K' else '{}000000'.format(x.group(1))` replacement either replaces with the Group 1 + `000` if Group 2 value is `K`, else, the Group 1 with `000000` appended to it is used.